# TypeError: 'score1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, typeerror

```
quiz_score.insert(count,total_score)

count1 = count + 1

print(StudentName, count1, quiz_score)

print(score1 = quiz_score[0])

print(score2 = quiz_score[1])

print(score3 = quiz_score[2])
```

My program outputs error: TypeError: 'score1' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Answer (score 3):

change `print(score1 = quiz_score[0])` to

`print('score1 =' +  str(quiz_score[0]))` or `print('score1 =', quiz_score[0])`

Accordingly change this for `score2` and `score3` aswell.

In your case you are using `print` as if `score1` is a keyword argument for `print` function which is not true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, followed your instructions:                         print('score1 =' + quiz_score[0])
 print('score2 =' + quiz_score[1])
 print('score3 =' + quiz_score[2])                                                                   but the program outputted:  
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly